# should I use new keywords in laravel's controllers

Tags: laravel, design-patterns

I know DI, Solid Principles, factory patterns, adapter pattern and many more maybe. Now let's say I am creating a laravel application and it's gonna be huge. Let's say I have a postscontroller which is resource and has CRUD methods. Now Let's say in that controller's functions, I have a post Model and use it to retrieve data from database. I have a store function where I am creating   new Post() and then put it into database.

1) Is it a good practice to have Post model directly in PostController's function and use new Post() also? What is bad in it? I know that this way I am not using dependency injection and patterns, but still why is it bad? As you know , I can still mock the object without dependency injection since laravel has so many amazing testing features. Then why is it that bad to write new keyword in controller's functions and also use Post model directly?

Comment: Where does it say you shouldn't use `new {Model}` in a Laravel controller function? Also, this question has far too many questions...

Comment: Because I CAN INJECT THIS MODEL THROUGH CONSTRUCTOR with the help of IOC and that's better because in later, it will be better for testing or many other things.

Comment: Right, but that doesn't mean you *shouldn't* use `new {Model}`, it just means that there's an *alternative*. Also, please don't type in all caps; it comes off as rude.

Comment: Testing a controller is questionable anyway. You have to mock too much stuff.

Answer (score 1):

To give you one answer to your question. There is this "Slim controllers, fat models" concept. I used to defer the object creation to the object itself by *Named Constructers*.

```
class UserController 
{
    public function create(UserCreateRequest $request)
    {
        $user = User::createFromRequest($request);

        // do anything else
    }
}

class User
{
    public static function createFromRequest(UserCreateRequest $request)
    {
        $user = new User;
        $user->first_name = $request->first_name;
        // ...
        $user->save();

        return $user;
    }
}
```

With this you can have more different constructors like `User::createAdmin` and its testable. You just need to mock the Request.